# pathos pool statement gets hanged

Tags: python, pathos

My program seems to not proceed further beyond the Pool(5) statement. I am using python 3.6 on windows server, 64 bit virtual machine with 8 virtual CPU's.

Code is as below

```
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp
 poolObj = mp.Pool(5)     
 docs = poolObj.map(nlp,textStr)
```

it gets hanged at the statement Pool(5). I tried with ProcessingPool(5) as well, same result.

Comment: I don't use `pathos` but I would assume that it will be bound by the same restriction as regular `multiprocessing` in that, on Windows, multiprocessing code should be shielded by `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: Although it seems the specific "Windows" section of the [Python 2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) is not in the [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) but made more general. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: The above code is inside a function main() which is being called from within if __name__ == '__main__':

Comment: Virtualized? There's probably a unit that controls the process cycles. You will need to get support from the virtual machine software provider. The problem you typed seems to have nothing to do with Python or Python modules.

Comment: ok, so any special settings need to be done to enable multiprocessing on VM?  are you aware of setting?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the `pathos` author.  First... it helps if you post a code snippet that can be executed by people attempting to answer your question.  That helps you get a better answer, as it can be diagnosed better (as in this case, it might be a serialization issue, or it might be the `freeze_support` windows issue, or it might be a build issue).

Here's what I can suggest in abstract of knowing more details:

- Do you have a C compiler?  If not, then you aren't actually using
  `multiprocess`, which is what `pathos` intends to use.  It's a fork
  of `multiprocessing` that has more capabilities.  If the answer is
  no, then you need to install one, and then rebuild `multiprocess`.
- You don't need to do run within `__main__` if you are using
  `multiprocess` (see above), however, on windows, you will need to use
  `pathos.helpers.freeze_support`.  It is *required* for pools on
  windows in most cases.
- If both of the above are fine, then I'd check if your object
  serializes, and on windows you can confirm if the object will pickle
  correctly for `multiprocess` with `dill.check` (in the `dill`
  package).

It also might be a combination of one or more of the above.

Comment: I did not have C compiler earlier but installed a tcc now.  I had installed pathos using conda forge which installed multiprocess and dill as well.   As per documentation at [link] (https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/), for python 3.3 + C compiler is suggested not mandatory though.   Considering I still need a C compiler, do I need to still download multiprocess and build separately or just installing pathos from conda forge will do?

Comment: I would rebuild `multiprocess` since you have added a C compiler.  You can test if the required C library is built by doing a `import _multiprocess`.  If this succeeds, then you are past the build issue.

Comment: I installed tcc and put it under C:/Apps/tcc and added it to to the system path. Downloaded the multiprocess source from GitHub, build and install.  I am getting a warning that "C extenstions may not be compiled".  Is the setup.py expecting the C compiler at a particular path? and can we specify it?

Comment: I am able to call `import _multiprocess` , so it seems c compile issue may not be there.  Also the Pool(5) statement is working.  It is hanging at the Pool.map(nlp, textStr) statement.  I checked with dill.pickles(textStr), it returned true.

Comment: I have put the complete code at the GitHub issues of multiprocess https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess/issues/43

Answer (score 0):

### Possible explanation

I had a similar issue, it took me ages to understand what happened, and I eventually discovered that **one of the processes was killed by the OOM killer** because it was using too much RAM.
Pathos could not detect this, and was waiting for the process to finish, although it had been killed (and a new idle one created instead).

On Ubuntu, you can check out the kernel messages to find out if the OOM killer has been triggered:

```
dmesg -T
```

Look for a line that mentions sth like:

> [Mon Jan 10 02:24:40 2022] Out of memory: Killed process 1420 (python) total-vm:14764496kB, anon-rss:13565716kB, file-rss:28kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:27652kB oom_score_adj:0

### To reproduce problem

If you want to try by yourself, you can reproduce the same behaviour with the following code snippet:

```py
import time
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool

def do_something(i):
    print(i, 'entering')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(i, 'returning')
    return i

with ProcessPool(2) as pool:
    results = pool.map(
        do_something,
        range(5)
    )
```

During the execution, you can use `htop` to kill one of the subprocesses (last 2 lines of my screenshot). If you do this, you'll end up in a hanging state: no CPU use, but the Python script never returns.

[image: htop multiprocessing]